# Using Alt Gr on external keyboard with Android 4.0.4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, external-keyboard

I have Sony Xperia P with official android 4.0.4 on board. The Polish language uses some letters, that normally (on PC) are typed by <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> (eg. <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>=ą). But using <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> on external keyboard does not work as intended on android. How to make it working correctly?

Comment: There is no <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> on a android keyboard... long press on the letter to get the popup of alternative variations of that letter, with umlauts, dashes etc...

Comment: @t0mm13b Sorry, forgot to mention that I want to use external keyboard... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution some time ago. The app [External Keyboard Helper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper) makes it work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's really not the solution. Solution is to fix this issue, please! Why is it so hard to get the alt-gr to work? Still the same issue in android 4.1.2.